# How to add text into PrimeNG speeddial option buttons?

Tags: angular, primeng, speed-dial

I want to print a text instead of icons in the options of my sppeddial component.

[image]

I want this.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

1. Define your model list in the component's TypeScript file (`component.ts`):

```js
this.items = [
  {
    icon: 'one',
    command: () => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'info',
        summary: 'Add',
        detail: 'Data Added',
      });
    },
  },
  {
    icon: 'two',
    command: () => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'success',
        summary: 'Update',
        detail: 'Data Updated',
      });
    },
  },
  {
    icon: 'pi pi-trash',
    command: () => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Delete',
        detail: 'Data Deleted',
      });
    },
  },
  {
    icon: 'pi pi-upload',
  },
  {
    icon: 'pi pi-external-link',
    url: 'http://angular.io',
  },
];
```

Feel free to change the icon property to any name you desire, as it will create a span element with a class corresponding to the icon name under the hood. This class will be used as a selector to specify your item.

2. Use the `p-speedDial` component in your component's HTML file (`component.html`):

```html
<p-speedDial [model]="items" direction="up"></p-speedDial>
```

3. In the component's SCSS file (`component.scss`), select the spans and change their content:

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .p-speeddial-action-icon.one::before {
  content: '1' !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-speeddial-action-icon.two::before {
  content: '2' !important;
}
```

These styles will change the icon content of the first two buttons to '1' and '2' respectively.

> *it's a workaround but it works*